# How to install Ruby plugin on Eclipse Indigo under Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: eclipse, ruby, plugins

I've had no luck installing the Ruby plugin in Eclipse Indigo v3.7.1 under Ubuntu Oneiric. The Ubuntu community notes apply to earlier versions and don't help much with my setup.

I wonder if you can point me at a more helpful on line resource/ set of instructions/ hand holding site?

Many thanks for reading this far: I hope someone can help.

Comment: The Aptana plug-in installs fine if you follow the directions on their website...or you can just use their portable eclipse instance

Comment: Are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If it throws an error about `.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.7.0_155965261/plugins/com.aptana.swt.webkitbrowser.linux.x86_64_1.0.0.1295409059/os/linux/x86_64/libcefjni.so:libjpeg.so.62`

Just:
`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`

Installed the full Aptana plugin on 12.04 LTS with eclipse from repo.